# SMTP errors with Sitecore emails

Tags: c#, email, smtp, sitecore

I have a site using C# and sitecore CMS I have a form which on submissions should send 2 e-mails 1 to the user who just filled it out based on the e-mail address they filled in and another to an admin user.

The admin e-mail goes through but the user e-mail fails and instead of posting back and getting a thank you message the user gets a 404 page.

The error is as follows:

```
Exception information: 
Exception type: SmtpException 
Exception message: Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.1.2 Recipient address rejected: User unknown 

    Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 18 
    Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    at System.Net.Mail.RecipientCommand.CheckResponse(SmtpStatusCode statusCode, String response)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.SendMail(MailAddress sender, MailAddressCollection recipients, String deliveryNotify, SmtpFailedRecipientException& exception)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at Wolftrap_CMS.layouts.PromotionRequestForms.PromotionProposalFormSublayout.SendUserEmail() in e:\CCNetWorkingFolders\Wolftrap\WebSite\layouts\PromotionRequestForms\PromotionProposalFormSublayout.ascx.cs:line 139
   at Wolftrap_CMS.layouts.PromotionRequestForms.PromotionProposalFormSublayout.btnSubmit_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\CCNetWorkingFolders\Wolftrap\WebSite\layouts\PromotionRequestForms\PromotionProposalFormSublayout.ascx.cs:line 153
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

The only difference between the emails is that one that the admin e-mail is set as from the entered address to a user at the local domain and the user e-mail is the reverse. (and a different subject line but that is unlikely relevant)

The code for the user email is:

```
PromotionRequestFormWrapper wrapper = new PromotionRequestFormWrapper(Sitecore.Context.Item);
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

        mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailReminder.FromAddress"]);

        mail.To.Add(txtContactEmail.Text);
        mail.Subject = fieldReplace(wrapper.UserEmailSubjectLine);

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

        string msg = fieldReplace(wrapper.UserEmailText);

        mail.Body = msg;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServer;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServerUserName, Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServerPassword);
        smtp.Port = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.MailServerPort;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtp.Send(mail);
```

Although this is a server issue because the user e-mail and the subsequent thank you page work fine locally, but not once the code is pushed remotely.

What settings might give such an error based only on a difference in the recipient and sender of the e-mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your SMTP server are allowing emails sent to local email address, but not as a relay to remote email Address.

It could be lots of things, but the typical reason is that the server only relays emails when it smtp client is authenticated with it.

Comment: I used a email address with the same domain as the website and the form went through fine, thanks!

Comment: Always use a trusted "from address" when sending emails.
Smtp serveres, can use SPF records on the domain, to white lists what servers, can send from the domain.

Comment: no the to address is what is the hang-up not the from address. As a test I sent the email to a local address and it was successfull

Answer (score 0):

This a SMTP problem,is not related to Sitecore. 
You can see [here](http://www.ecdoe.gov.za/ecdoe/files/AnswersThatWork-SMTP_Server_Error_and_Status_Codes.pdf) : what mean exactly 5.1.2 error.

For such a case a have a SMTP Testing Winform Application that is copying to server and I am checking  if SMTP is working.

I suggest you to contact System Administration and put him to check if SMTP is working for your emails.